# yarn start /yarn run not works Wireguard project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-install, hadoop-yarn, npm-start

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiUC2.png)
**This is wireguard project**
https://github.com/ngoduykhanh/wireguard-ui

1. I clone the above repo
2. Then just install node modules
3. And yarn start

*yarn start*

**it opens a terminal with project path**

and index.js missing from project

u can see project structure in screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQfvm.png)

Comment: Have you read the instructions in the project page? Those 3 steps are nowhere to be found in that github page

Comment: then how to run the project

Comment: download the appropriate file depending on your operating system from [releases](https://github.com/ngoduykhanh/wireguard-ui/releases) - extract the one and only file in it (wireguard-ui in the case of linux) and run that as instructed by the git page you linked to

Comment: If you want to BUILD it from source, then that's when you clone the repo, and then, you run the commands, again as documented on that github page

Comment: yes i run that file but i want to customize that ui and make build again

Comment: well, then follow the [build instructions](https://github.com/ngoduykhanh/wireguard-ui#build-binary-file)

Comment: this is build cmd firstly i wanted to run this project locally on my machine

Comment: then build it first, or download the binary - it'sup to you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.